# Draw an image on a canvas slowly, left to right, in a particular place on the canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I've loaded an image, so I have an Image object, which I wish to draw slowly left to right at a specific coordinate of the canvas, using pure javascript. I have no difficulty with doing an animation.

I have a preference for creating a pattern as it fits in with existing logic. Creating a pattern from the image forces the first image to start in coord 0,0, and then is repeated but the origins of each repeat may not fall on the coordinate I want for the image, which is determined at run time.

Any suggestions or alternative approaches much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern, and still be able to define where the (0,0) of the pattern will be : for that use translate() : the pattern will have its (0,0) in the new coordinate system, which means it will be translated just as well.

A small demo using a translated pattern :

http://jsbin.com/jeyeripu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @markE : thx, i tried to do some effect with a few l.o.c. like in the old 1K contest of old times ... :-)  Completely out of topic, but i tried something recently you might enjoy (you can play with the parameter section, including useBitmapTiles :-) ) http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/zF2w8/2/

Answer (score 0):

What about putting a div on top of your image, animating it away with jQuery? Look at below solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        .box{
          width:300px;
          height: 300px;
          position: absolute;
        }

        #img {

          background-image: url(img.jpg);
          background-size: contain;
          z-index: 1;
        }

        #overlay{
          background-color:white;
          z-index: 2;
        }

      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {

          $("#overlay").animate({
            width: "0"
          }, 5000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            console.log("done");
          });

        });

      </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="box" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="box" id="img"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: My image isn't on the page so I haven't used your solution for this particular situation, but I've saved your suggestion. Many thanks